# Что означает запись вида $Timer->start ();

Tags: php

```
$Timer->start ();
```

"->" - Для чего данная стрелка?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Доступ к членам класса.

Почитай про ООП. Например [тут](http://php.su/learnphp/phpoo/?classes)

Answer (score 0):

эта стрелка разделяет имя класса и имя метода этого класса.

Comment: Только ли "имя метода"?  @victor_crimea, не стоит нести чушь...

Comment: в данном случае имя метода. потому что это функция

Comment: зря минусов натыкали... +1

Comment: Вот только не имя класса, а имя объекта. А если бы слева было имя класса, а справа - имя статичного метода, то это было бы уже не стрелка `->`, а двойное двоеточие `::`